# Get a list of objects that have the same value for a specific property

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of objects that have a `.type` property assigned them.

All the objects are in an array like this:

```
var arr    = [];
    arr[0] = {'type':1,'x':56,'y':2};
    arr[1] = {'type':2,'x':1, 'y':23};
    arr[2] = {'type':1,'x':23,'y':63};
```

What i would like to do is return a list of all the objects that have for example `type == 1`.

Is there any built in way to do or will I have to iterate each one individually and push those that match to a new array?

Comment: You can use `filter`: `arr.filter(function (el) { return el.type === 1; });`

Comment: @c.P.u1 do you know how the filter works in terms of how it finds all the objects at the bare bones level? Does it still iterate to find them all  ? I need to know so i can see if i should put it inside my game loop or setup the list before the game loop to reduce the impact of frame rate?

Comment: Yes, it iterates and returns a new array. Check the documentation: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @Dave -  If iterating all the elements in the array,using the `filter()` method,  is of concern, do check out my answer of storing them as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If iterating all the `n` elements in the array is of concern, then you could construct your data structure as an `object` and not an `array`:

```
var multimap = {};
multimap[1] = [{'type':1,'x':56,'y':2},{'type':1,'x':23,'y':63}];
multimap[2] = [{'type':2,'x':1, 'y':23}];
```

and you can retrieve the elements of a particular type in `order of 1`, like:
`multimap[1]` will give you the elements of type `1`.

Inserting a new element of a particular `type` into the `arr` structure:

```
if(!multimap[type]){
  multimap[type] = [];
}
multimap[type].push(element);
```

Comment: Since you are implementing a multimap, I'd prefer that "arr" be named better, like "multimap".  But still worth a +1.

Answer (score 1):

in js 1.6 you can use the filter function like so:

var result = arr.filter(function(o){return o.type == 1})

...instead of creating and pushing to a new array inside a for loop 
technically both of them do the same thing, but filter is elegant as it abstracts the ugliness

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.filter` function of the array:

```js
var arr = [{
  'type': 1,
  'x': 56,
  'y': 2
}, {
  'type': 2,
  'x': 1,
  'y': 23
}, {
  'type': 1,
  'x': 23,
  'y': 63
}];
var filtered = arr.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.type === 1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i = arr.length;i++){
if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty('type')) {
 alert('have key!');
 }
}
```

Using this you can search any property not just `type` . If you pass property name as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `.filter()` function in Javascript.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var arr    = [];

arr[0] = {'type':1,'x':56,'y':2};
arr[1] = {'type':2,'x':1, 'y':23};
arr[2] = {'type':1,'x':23,'y':63};

var filteredArr = arr.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.type === 1;  // filter the objects with type 1
});

console.dir(filteredArr);  // check your console
```

Readup: 
[`.filter()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by @c.P.u1, the filter iterates the array internally. If you think from the algorithmic point of view, you will have to iterate over the data to filter something out.